# Modelagem de base de dados

Tags: mysql, modelagem

Criei a seguinte modelagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de saber o que pode ser melhorado? levando em considerações boas práticas para banco de dados?

**Explicação:**

Na `TBLogin` uma pessoa irá criar um login, podendo ser do tipo `PessoaFisica` ou `PessoaJuridica`. OBS: Neste caso uma `PessoaJuridica` = `Empresa`

Na `TBPessoas` coloquei os campos que são comuns para ambos os tipo de pessoa.

`TBEndereco` `TBCidades` `TBEstados` são para armazenar a localização.

`TBVagas` relacionada com a `TBPessoaJuridica`(Empresa). Seria as vagas que essa pessoa/empresa cadastrariam para divulgar.

`TBCurriculos` Toda `PessoaFisica` pode ter apenas um currículo. O currículo é composto pela `TBIdiomas` que no caso seria os idiomas que a pessoa fala, podendo haver + de 1.

`TBEmpregos` É um histórico profissional de onde a pessoa já trabalhou.
`TBFormacoes` São as formações que um pessoa tem.(Colégio/Faculdade/Cursos)
`TBTiposFormacoes` são os tipos de formação. Ex: (graduação / pos-graduação / mestrado / doutorado / ensino médio / etc)

**OBS:** Não sou muito bom com modelagens, tenho pouco conhecimento de relacionamentos de tabelas e essa coisas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> A resposta foi invalidada pela edição da pergunta, mas fica aqui quem quiser ver em cima da [original](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/89015/1).

É sempre difícil sem conhecer os reais requisitos. O que pode ser certo em uma caso pode ser errado em outro.

Não achei nenhum erro grave como se costuma ver em muitos modelos. De uma maneira geral gostei de tudo, até dos detalhes, exceto por prefixar as tabelas com `TB` e nomear as tabelas no plural. Claro que as informações são escassas. As tabelas possuem poucas colunas. O que eu vejo é que cadastros reais costumam possuir mais dados. Mas pode não ser o seu caso. Pode ser que pretende ampliar depois. Aí o modelo pode começar ficar errado. Mas só posso falar do que estou vendo agora.

O que eu não gosto mas não posso afirmar que está errado sem saber dos detalhes:

- Ter uma tabela de relacionamento de pessoas com endereços dependendo se é física ou jurídica. Faz algo sentido fazer assim mas eu não faria. Acho que é duplicação de esforço na maioria dos casos.
- Acho estranho turno estar vinculado a currículo, mas vai saber se tem algum motivo. Talvez seja qual o turno de interesse da pessoa. Ela pode ter vários, certo? Pensou nisto?
- Obviamente há um simplificação e rigidez do que pode haver em um currículo mas não posso discutir isto no caso concreto. Inclusive dependendo do cargo é provável que tabelas específicas podem ser necessárias para informar sobre certos tipos de habilidades. Mas é só especulação minha. Dá para ser criativo aqui.

Ah, o posicionamento do diagrama poderia dar mais ênfase para as tabelas mais importantes e deixar mais claro como satélites as menos importantes, secundárias, complementares. Mas nada que afete o modelo, claro.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Marginal para sua pergunta, mas seguindo a dica do bigown sobre organização do diagrama: procure por raiz agregada, que é um conceito que aborda a determinação dos 'galhos ' principais'. Mais voltado para quando implementar as regras de negócio que vão manipular seus dados, mas obviamente ajuda a organizar o diagrama.

Comment: Atualizei o esquema. e tentei explicar mais ou menos como é que funciona.

Comment: Na prática, quanto mais simples melhor. Tanto para entender a dinâmica como para trazer os relacionamentos dos dados. procure sempre adotar a ideia de que toda o MER sempre pode ser melhorado, e que no futuro, ele deve poder ser expandido, então seja o mais abstrato possível, nunca crie tabelas desnecessárias só para o intuito de expandir sua arquitetura, seja objetivo. No geral, dá pra melhorar... Enxugue o máximo que poder. Quer saber como melhorar, comece fazendo um caso de uso primeiro...

Answer (score 3):

Do meu ponto de vista o modelo esta praticamente correto.

A única alteração que eu faria seria a seguinte:

```
Pessoa -> Endereco (1..N)
Pessoa -> PessoaFisica (1..1)
Pessoa -> PessoaJuridica (1..1)
```

Assim eliminando as tabelas :
- `TBPessoasFisicas_has_TBEndereco`.
- `TBPessoaasJuridicas_has_TBEndereco`.

Afinal, pessoa tem endereço, não importa se é jurídica ou física.
Assim criando `TBPessoa_has_TBEndereco`.

Eu não compreendi a tabela de `Vagas`, relacionada com pessoa jurídica, afinal você esta identificando a pessoa, `Vagas` estaria melhor relacionada com uma tabela de `Empresa`, pois a empresa tem vagas.

Comment: Neste caso `PessoaJuridica` = 'Empresa'